# How to change the title color of a single window?

Tags: compiz

In an attempt to ease the navigation between the many windows on my desktop, I would like to give each one of them a different title color. Is this possible?

I have 12.04 with Unity.

Comment: But I suspect it isn't possible because there just one window manager running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible without programming compiz or a compiz plugin.

Comment: compiz plugin seems like a good option - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: A plugin to compiz which changes colours of windows and/or decorations.

Comment: And how can I find and install such a plugin?

Comment: It would need to be developed (created) before you could find it or install it.